# Chrome browser is unable to show this image

Tags: http, liferay, content-type, cdn

To open this [link](http://cdn.www.liferay.com/image/software_catalog?img_id=433264&t=1326942691281) with chrome 15 will pop up a download dialog, but not on IE 8 .

Any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Content-Type returned from the server when fetching the link is;

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

...which is not a valid image type. IE8 may try to show it anyway, which Chrome apparently won't.

From [Microsoft's documentation on mime type detection in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775147(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A MIME type is ambiguous if it is "text/plain,"
>   "application/octet-stream," an empty string, or null (that is, the
>   server failed to provide it).

A bit farther down the page;

> If the server-provided MIME type is either known or ambiguous, the
>   buffer is scanned in an attempt to verify or obtain a MIME type from
>   the actual content.

This is why IE succeeds while Chrome (that doesn't guess) fails to display the image and tries to download the file instead.

Comment: Yes, return a valid content type for the image; for example image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif depending on what the image actually is. That is a server configuration, you usually set up so that it uses the file suffix (jpg) to detect what mime type to send and it'll do it for all files with that suffix.

Comment: @爱国者 Seeing that your file is probably served by a script, it's probably the script serving the file that needs to set the correct content type. How that works depends on the scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

The server response says

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

So the server is saying that the content is a generic file to be downloaded, not an image.

These two pages may be useful:

- https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12025129
- http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-252

They both refer to editing the file `content-types.properties` adding the correct mime type.

Comment: But it can display on IE 8:-)

Comment: IE is too lax. The only correct way to show images reliably is to set the correct mime type in the response.