# How to get an image's base64 data in postman

Tags: file-upload, imageurl

**The question**

How do I get base64 data from an online image within postman?

**Context**

I'm doing a migration within postman. One part of this is migrating embedded images within messages. The embedded images are inserted in the html like this:

```html
<img src="https://attachment.freshdesk.com/inline/attachment?token=LongTokenHere" data-id="9198554508" alt="image.png" width="562" height="181">
```

**Goal**

Replace the image link with base64 data like this:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" data-id="9198554508" alt="image.png" width="562" height="181"/>
```

**Progress**

I can download the image's data in which I assume is byte data, convert it to ascii (which I assume is the base64 format), and upload it. But when uploading it like that, it ends up as a broken/unviewable image.

```js
pm.sendRequest(link, (err, res) => {
    err ? reject(err)
        : resolve({link, raw: res.text(), imageData: btoa(res.text())});
});
```

This does get me what seems to be base64 data: (a small snippet from the full file) `/VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAmcAAAD9CAYAAAD9bSdzAAAgAElEQVR4Af39f2xc/f39/f39/f1xV/1X/f26N0oUdSkrEP12/f0iAWkr/f39Bf0obTf9/Qv9/f1y/SH9OG40dXH9/TAQ/`

**Other things I tried**

Within postman, I can `get` the link, and then the body preview shows the image as it's supposed to look. I can then `save response to file`, which shows a working png. When comparing both sources in notepad++, they do look alike for a bit:

[image]

I also tried to see what happened when trying to convert the base64 data to a file using https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file, there I got this message:
`Your browser cannot display the file as “application/octet-stream”.`. I'm unsure what to do with that information as the response headers show me `content-type: image/png`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the Content type of the server returns Content-Type: application/octet-stream. Which is not a valid image type. IE8 may try to show it anyway, which Chrome apparently won't.

Please refer to this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046157/23185565

Comment: The strange thing is that the response shows content-type: image/png. I even set the accept: image/png and it still gives me the same response.

Comment: IE8!?! Hopefully no one is using that old browser... but that's part of the problem with copying content without thinking from other answers. We frown on that. Once you get enough rep, you can flag a question as a duplicate (if an answer answers both questions equally well, the questions are duplicates).

Comment: I am a bit confused, but hope you mean this answer as the duplicate and not my question, as it's not related to browsers at all.